# c# project transfer to other PC

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2010

i have created a project written c# using visual studio 2010 with crystal report.
Now my question is it is gonna work on other PC or do i need to install visual studio also and crystal report.

PS
i'm just gonna copy the project file and open the app in bin folder.
Thank you hope you all understand me.

Comment: If you want to "just execute" it on the other machine, you normally have to copy only the build output files. (e.g. /bin/Release folder)
But it depends on how you are implementing it and on which dependencies you rely on. 
If you want to work/change the code after the move, you have to setup the same on the other machine.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: sorry i cant try i only 1 PC right now

Comment: So  i need to install also visual studio also on other PC? and crystal report?for VS2010? in oder to chage the code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine (32 bit or 64 bit, depending on what version your app is targeting). You get that install from: https://www.crystalreports.com/crystal-reports-visual-studio/

hth,
- Ido